# Conditionally enable Jenkins declarative pipeline options?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Does Jenkins provide any functionality to achieve the following pipeline described below?

```
pipeline
{
    agent any
    options
    {
        when {
            branch 'master'
        }
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }
    stages { ... }
}
```

I have two states for repositories which this single pipeline must manage:

1. Build for commits to merge-requests branches (*pre-merge*), allow builds to be run concurrently
2. Build the master branch on merge of merge-requests (*post-merge*), do not allow builds to be run concurrently.

Comment: You’re asking for declarative pipeline - I assume scripted Pipeline would not be an option?

Comment: Sorry for the very long response time, but yes that is the case...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Lockable Resources Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/lockable-resources/) to guarantee that the problematic steps do not run in parallel when on the master branch.

Something like:

```
stage('on master') {
    when {
        branch 'master'
    }
    steps {
        lock(label: 'choose_a_label') {
            // your steps
        }
    }
}


stage('not on master') {
    when {
        not {
            branch 'master'
        }
    }
    steps {
        // your steps
    }
}
```

Comment: Unlike `disableConcurrentBuilds()`, this approach will consume a node "seat" while it waits.  I would only use it as a last resort.

Answer (score 2):

@Chadi's answer is certainly correct and the *Lockable Resources Plugin* seems the only easy workaround as for now. The [Jenkins documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/)(*Example 22. beforeOptions*) shows an example that is very similar to what you want to do. Here another possible solution (not tested):

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            stages {
                stage('on master') {
                    when {
                        beforeOptions true
                        branch 'master'
                    }
                    options {
                        lock label: 'master_build'
                    }
                    steps {
                        ...
                    }
                }
                stage('not on master') {
                    when {
                        not {
                            branch 'master'
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have used nested stages to group them in the same stage but it is not mandatory, of course. The benefit I see are:

- Locking now belongs to the stage `options` and the `steps` declaration contains steps and nothing else
- The whole stage is locked and you do not risk to put some statements outside of the `lock` block
- Personally, too many indentation levels reduce the readability, so if I can get rid of even one of them I am more than happy to do it.

The disadvantage is that you have to add a couple of lines and the `beforeOptions`, necessary to evaluate the `when` condition before `options`.